Folland: Extension of a linear map from locally integrable function to distributions
G. Folland in his book "Real Analysis" mentions a general way extending linear operators from functions to distributions, see the highlighted text here. I am sure this must be a theorem in some textbook/monograph but I could not find it. I checked the references that he mentions but I could not find anything relevant.
Can anyone point me to a textbook, monograph, or research paper that formally states and proves this result? I'd appreciate any help in finding a reliable source for this result.

Please don't use pictures.
